# How to merge two dataframes and retain only unique data from initial dataframes without duplicates?

Tags: r, dataframe, merge, filtering

I have two different dataframes (`df1` and `df2`, both of same length), with the same factors (with the rows not being in the same order for each dataframe) but with different numeric values (with `num_1` and `num_2` being different types of measurements):

```
df1:
     factor1 factor2 num_1
1          A    Y    1
2          A    Y    2
3          A    Z    3
4          A    Z    4

df2:
     factor1 factor2 num_2
1          A    Z    15
2          A    Z    16
3          A    Y    17
4          A    Y    18
```

I get duplicates when I use `merge`, which makes sense since each combination of factors appears multiple times (as multiple samples) without a specific id attached to it:

```
md1 <- merge(df1, df2,by.x=c("factor1","factor2"), 
                             by.y=c("factor1","factor2"))

     factor1 factor2 num_1 num_2
1          A    Y    1     17
2          A    Y    1     18
3          A    Y    2     17
4          A    Y    2     18
5          A    Z    3     15
6          A    Z    3     16
7          A    Z    4     15
8          A    Z    4     16
```

Now, I specifically want a merged dataframe that matches the lowest value of num_1 with the lowest value of num_2, aswell as the second lowest value of both columns up until the highest values of each column (as the actual dataframe has more than two samples per combination of factors), like the following example:

```
     factor1 factor2 num_1 num_2
1          A    Y    1     17
2          A    Y    2     18
3          A    Z    3     15
4          A    Z    4     16
```

I have tried using `distinct`, but that just returns a dataframe with 1 row (seemingly random?) of each combination of factors (while want to keep the same length of the dataframe before merging), for example:

```
md2 <- md1 %>% distinct(num_1, .keep_all = TRUE) %>% distinct(num_2, .keep_all = TRUE)

     factor1 factor2 num_1 num_2
1          A    Y    2     17
2          A    Z    3     15
```

I figured I could also try to put `df1` and `df2` in the same order and than attach just column `num_2` to `df1`, but I feel this is error prone and the values of `num_1` and `num_2` still would not match.

Is there any (elegant) way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we can assume the two dfs can be perfectly aligned (i.e. each has the same number of rows and the same combinations of factor levels) then your final suggestion should work. To make it more robust, you could first check if the dfs align correctly with `all.equal()`, and handle failures however you prefer.

```
library(dplyr)
## Create dfs
df1 <- data.frame(f1 = factor(rep("A", 4)),
                  f2 = factor(c("Y", "Y", "Z", "Z")),
                  num1 = c(1,2,3,4))

df2 <- data.frame(f1 = factor(rep("A", 4)),
                  f2 = factor(c("Z", "Z", "Y", "Y")),
                  num2 = c(15,16,17,18))

# Align dfs 
df1 <- df1 %>% arrange(f1, f2, num1) 
df2 <- df2 %>% arrange(f1, f2, num2)

# Check that dfs are correctly aligned
if(!all.equal(df1[,c('f1','f2')], df2[,c('f1','f2')])){
    print("Failed to align.")
}

# Copy column across
df1$num2 <- df2$num2

df1
  f1 f2 num1 num2
1  A  Y    1   17
2  A  Y    2   18
3  A  Z    3   15
4  A  Z    4   16
```